Hide port in the url deployed at iis using reverse proxy
i need a little help in hiding port number( in url ) in iis since i am new to iis .
I have these two vueJs apps in my iis
http:localhost:5000
http:localhost:5001
Now when i access this, the port number are displayed in the url for each website.
Now i know that only port 80 ( default port for http ) will not be shown in the url.
Someone suggested to use reverse proxy for hiding/redirecting purpose. Is it possible ?
I tried to write some rewrite rules but nothing seems to work


Someone suggested to use reverse proxy for hiding/redirecting purpose. Is it possible ?

If you just want to hide the port number, this method is feasible, and the example in the official documentation has demonstrated it well:  Access the content of the actual url http://localhost:8081/default.aspx through the entering url http://localhost/webmail/default.aspx.

I tried to write some rewrite rules but nothing seems to work

How do you deploy your Vue.js app? Following this example, simply modifying it should work, something like this:
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Reverse Proxy to Vue1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^Vue1/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5000/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Reverse Proxy to Vue2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^Vue2/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5001/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>

